# JAVA - Get HTTP request headers

Tags: java, http, httprequest

I have the following code

```
String jsonText = "some_text_in_json_format";
WebTarget target = "some_url/id"
Response response = target.resolveTemplate("id", id).queryParam("overwrite", false).request(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                .header("Authorization", "Basic " + authInfo).put(Entity.json(jsonText));
```

I need to retrieve the REQUEST headers.
I know how to get them if I had a HttpServletRequest object.

ADD: In addition to the Authorization header explicitly provided, does the request contain additional headers?

But in this case I found no methods (in the WebTarget or Invocation.Builder interfaces) to address my goal.

Any tips?

Thanks!

Comment: presumably you also have a Client? You can get ClientResponseContext from that and get a handle on headers from there

Comment: @David The code refers to the client application. Are there other headers which are implicitly add to a request, in addition to the Authentication one? I can only debug the code, since is not mine. So I need to exactly know what type of request is sent to the server (which cannot be checked).

Comment: @Fab Please see my updated [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47183662/1426227).

Answer (score 1):

> In addition to the `Authorization` header explicitly provided, does the request contain additional headers?

Yes. For the code posted in your question, at least the following headers will be added to your request:

- `Host: <host>:<port>`
- `Accepts: application/json`
- `Content-Type: application/json`

---

You can use a [`ClientRequestFilter`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/client/ClientRequestFilter.html) to get the headers from the request:

```java
public class MyClientRequestFilter implements ClientRequestFilter {

    @Override
    public void filter(ClientRequestContext requestContext) throws IOException {

        MultivaluedMap<String, Object> headers = requestContext.getHeaders();
        ...

    }
}
```

Then register the filter in your client instance:

```java
Client client = ClientBuilder.newClient().register(MyClientRequestFilter.class);
```